# array in prepared statement not working

Tags: php

I want to create a prepared statement with an array called `$params`. When I run my script I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
>   /home/morea/directory-new.php on line 110

line 110 is `$stmt->bind_param('i', $place_holders);`

```
$params = array(5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 3, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 4, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42);
/* Create a string for the parameter placeholders filled to the number of params */
$mysqli = new MySQLi("localhost", "erpa", "48p", "le3");
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
$place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?'));
$sth = ("SELECT u.url, COUNT(u.url) AS total, u.SiteTypeID, p.SiteType FROM sites AS u LEFT JOIN sitetypes AS p USING (SiteTypeID) WHERE SiteTypeID=($place_holders)");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sth);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $place_holders);
$stmt->execute($params);
$query5 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sth);

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3, MYSQLI_ASSOC) && $row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($query5, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
if ($row4['SiteType'] == 'selected'){
    $list .= $row4['total'];
    $list .= '<option value="'.$row4['SiteTypeID'].'"';
     $list .= "selected='selected'>";
    $list .= $row4['SiteType'];
    $list .= "</option>";
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `mysqli_query($dbc, $sth);` in there?

Comment: to use fetch_array with my sql statement

Comment: That's not correct use of `mysqli_query`.

Comment: How to do I use mysqli fetch array from my sql statement listed here, or in another way retrieve data from that query

Comment: Check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You should check $stmt after calling prepare(). It is probably false because your query should use `WHERE SiteTypeID IN ($place_holders)` not `WHERE SiteTypeID=($place_holders);`

EDIT: (should now cover all issues and be an acceptable answer)
Additionally (thanks Rocket!) bind_params() expects a parameter list, not an array, and execute() needs no params at all. Double check the php docs for these function at http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php. If you want to bind to an array, consider using PDO which I find much nicer to code than mysqli anyhow.

Comment: Hi Rob, just tried what you said, and it seems to help, but now I get the error Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Comment: @user3286022: `$stmt->bind_param('i', $sti);`.  You're binding multiple `?`s but only sending a value for one of 'em.

Comment: Hi Rocket, ok, well I tried it with $stmt->bind_param('i', $place_holders); instead and it tells me Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement . I counted the number of items in my array and they match the number of items in my table.

Comment: @user3286022: You can't send `bind_param` an array.  You need to send it one argument per each `?`.

Comment: if you call bind_params() do you still need to pass $params again in the execute() call? Also, what Rocket said. I like PDO soooo much better than mysqli.

Comment: @RobP: `execute()` doesn't take any parameters in MySQLi.

Comment: @RocketHazmat right that's what I am saying, he's passing a param that should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send `bind_param` a value for *each* `?` you have in your query.  It also needs the values to be references.  Also, `->execute()` doesn't take any parameters.  Finally, `mysqli_query()` is incorrect here.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sth);

$boundParams = array(str_repeat('i', count($params)));
foreach($params as &$val){
    $boundParams[] =& $val;
}
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $boundParams);

$stmt->execute();    
$query5 = $stmt->get_result();

// then you can run mysqli_fetch_array on $query5
```

<sub>NOTE: `get_result()` requires you have the mysqlnd driver installed.</sub>

P.S. `WHERE SiteTypeID=($place_holders)` should be `WHERE SiteTypeID IN ($place_holders)`.